# CSS - grid loses structure when howering over

Tags: css, wordpress, formatting, grid

So I made this webpage for a client and I have a problem that has been driving me crazy.
When you go to this part of the home page there is this "grid-like" section where you can choose the various products modells. As soon as you hover over the third item (LIBRA - PERGOLA CON TETTO IN VETRO) the lower row goes crazy.

https://www.pergolaorius.it/#modelli

Could you guys please help? Thank you very much

Comment: The problem is in your carousel settings. Even on mobile you have issues. If you share your settings to look or go to owl carousel documentation. There you will see how to define responsive settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.